# Sort combinations by sum of its elements in Python

Tags: python, sorting, combinations, python-itertools

**I have a huge list of integers in Python (1000000+ elements)**, but I will illustrate what I need with an example for the sake of simplicity. Let's suppose I have this list:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,100]
```

Now I'd like to get all the combinations (size 3) of that list, so I use itertools.

```
combinations = itertools.combinations(A,3)
```

But my problem is that this will return the combinations in lexicographical order:

```
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,2,100)
(1,3,4)
```

and so on.

**I'd like to get the combinations sorted by the sum of its elements**. That would be:

(1,2,3) which sums 6, 
(1,2,4) which sums 7,
(1,3,4) which sums 8,

and so on so forth.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd give each combination a summed value and sort by that value as a key `[(1,2,3),6]` - along those lines

Comment: Have you estimated how many combinations are involved?

Comment: The number of combinations is going to be huge, since there are more than one million elements on the list

Comment: Are you even going to have enough memory to store this many combinations? My guesstimate is that it would require about 1.2e10 **gigabytes**

Comment: it seems like you are trying to use brute force on a problem like knapsack problem. if you describe the actual problem, there is probably a better way to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ordered combinations too big to fit in memory

The number of combinations for 1,000,000 things taken 3 at a time is 166,666,166,667,000,000.  That is too big to fit in memory, too big to sort, and too huge to even loop over in a reasonable amount of time.

For a way to generate these combinations lazily, see ["GENERATING ALL COMBINATIONS"](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc3a.pdf) in Donald Knuth's fascicle on *Combinatorial Algorithms*.

### Ordered combinations that can fit in memory

As long as the number of combinations is reasonable, the most straight forward approach is to directly sort the combinations by their sum:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint

>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100]
>>> combinations = sorted(itertools.combinations(A, 3), key=sum)
>>> pprint.pprint(combinations)
[(1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 100),
 (1, 3, 100),
 (1, 4, 100),
 (2, 3, 100),
 (2, 4, 100),
 (3, 4, 100)]
```

The technique uses [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) as a [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) for [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

### Bridging the two worlds

When [nCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is bigger than can be practically enumerated, it would make sense to reduce the problem by removing the larger elements from list *A* until the sum gets big enough to include those values.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to consider here is the no.of combinations is really huge ~(1000000)^^3
So, any sorting algorithm with O(NlogN) is going to be bad. We need something in O(N).

We can try create a SortedDictionary ([sorteddict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorteddict)) or use a standard external hash implementation like memcache to store the combination as
{sum:[tuple1, tuple2]}. Complexity for this operation will be ~O(N)

Then, Create a new list, loop through the cache and all values to it. Again the complexity will be O(N).

Overall, we will have O(2N) which is efficient than O(NLogN). Hope this will help!

Comment: I'm not following how your approach would reduce the time complexity of sorting by the sum of the values... Essentially, you create a map `sum:List[tuples]`, and then you iterate over it again, but how does this *sort* by `sum`? Any ordered dictionary implementation that maintais a sorted order, I think, has to use some insertion operation that is more than O(N), no?

Comment: I am not sure about your statement 'Any ordered dictionary implementation that maintais a sorted order, I think, has to use some insertion operation that is more than O(N)' on ordered list. I guess there are better ways to deal than sorting at every insertions like have the hash key as an index into memory or something like that. Agree for some cases we may need to do some sort & copy - but that can be amortized. May be Lets check how it is actually implemented and discuss.

Comment: I ask out of genuine curiosity, I've only taken a few cursory CS classes, since my background is biology, so my depth of knowledge beyond basic algorithms/data-structures is rather limited. But basically, I'm not sure how your approach above provides a *sorted* sequence of tuples...

Comment: If tuples sum order is guaranteed, then its just a iteration through the entire dictionary and generate the new list of combinations. The new list of combinations will be in the same order right?

Comment: Well, if you use an `collections.OrderedDict`, then this list will be in the same order, but that order won't be *sorted*.

Comment: You are right about OrderedDict. Thanks for pointing. Python supports something like sorteddict as well. Ref:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorteddict  Modified the answer as well.

Comment: Yes, [this](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) is quickly becoming the canonical library for such containers. I hear rumblings about it being added to the Standard Library. However, you will note, that the [insertion into the sorted containers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) is still more than O(N), even if it is implemented very efficiently.

Comment: For sorteddict, I can see functions like bisect, bisect_key, bisect_left, ... definitely insert is not O(n). May be other components like sorted list may have O(n)

Comment: No, `SortedList` is the backbone of the rest of the containers I believe. But regardless, how *could* it have O(N) sorted insert?

Comment: Key task is to maintain the order and finding position for the new item. A binary search based approach for finding new item's key position can be done in O(logN). Without any shifts the copy operation will be straight forward O(1). This is my understanding on reading the documentation. Maybe I try to write some code over the weekend to check this theory.

Comment: There's really not much difference between `O(n)` and `O(n.log n)`, even for `n = 1000000**3`